# Codeanywhere: Preview link for node.js

Tags: node.js, codeanywhere

I started using codeanywhere a few week ago.I started my first node.js project with express and socket.io.But I don't know how to get the preview page of my server.Can anybody help me with that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE, right-click your project Connection.  In the menu, select "info" to have a doc open in the editor that lists the preview URL.